# Gradient scale size is not calculated correctly in Highcharts map

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[In this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/g8hLy4j5/10/) I have a Highcharts world map where each country color depends on a related value (that's the country GDP in trillions USD). The values go from 0 to 21. If you look at US and China, these countries are in a different color from the rest of the world.

The issue is that the gradient scale goes from zero to 100 (this is automatically set by Highcharts), and since all the countries are below 25 they all have the same color with the exception of two.

[image]

Shouldn't Highcharts detect that the largest value is 21 and have the scale up to, say, 25 instead of 100? Is there an error in how I'm defining the map options? What's the best way to approach this?

```
Highcharts.mapChart('container', content);
```

Comment: There is something wrong with your demo link, I can't open it. But from your description, I assume that the setting the `colorAxis.max` can help: https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/colorAxis.max

Comment: Thanks, the link is kind of slow, you need to wait a minute until the map is displayed. But what is the best way to determine the max?

Answer (score 0):

I calculated the min max and set it in colorAxis.max. To do that, I first calculated the standard deviation of the data points, then removed any points that were not included within two standard deviations from the mean. Once the outliers are discarded, I took the min and the max.